# Trigger observables chain only if there was a button click

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like to execute `toggleButtonOnClick$()` function from the service, only when I click on a button. This function will save current state, service will later receive this change and update usersObs$.

Whenever the above mentioned happens, the `toggleButtonOnClick$` gets executed a few more times, even if I didn't click on the button again.

How can I prevent this and make this function only execute when I do `.next()` on the clickSubject and not when userObs$ changes?

I will write an example of the whole situation

**ButtonComponent**

```
private userClick = new Subject<null>();
private obs1$: Observable<string>();
private obs2$: Observable<string>();
private obs3$: Observable<boolean>();

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.obs2$ = this.obs1$.pipe(
      switchMap((value) => this.someService.getSomePropBasedOnValue$(value))
   );

   this.obs3$ = this.obs2$.pipe(
      switchMap((value) => this.someService.checksAndReturnsBoolean$(value))

   this.subscriptions.add(
      this.someService.toggleButtonOnClick$(this.obs2$, this.userClick).subscribe()
   )
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.subscriptions.unsuscribe();
}

onClick(): void {
   // emit a value when click on button to start observable chain
   this.userClick.next();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div 
        [attr.tooltip]="(obs3$ | async) ? 
            ('text_translation_1' | transloco)
            : ('text_translation_2' | transloco)"
        >
        <span 
            *ngIf="(obs3$ | async) && !isHovering"
            >
            Something here
        </span>

        <span 
            *ngIf="(obs3$ | async) && isHovering"
            >
            Something here
        </span>

        <span 
            *ngIf="!(obs3$ | async)"
            >
            Something here
        </span>
    </div>
```

**SomeService**

```
    public checksAndReturnsBoolean$(id): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.userObs$.pipe(
           map((users) => { users.some(((user) => user.id === id)) }
        );
    }

    public getSomePropBasedOnValue$(id): Observable<SomeObject | null> {
        return this.userObs$.pipe(
           map((users) => { users.find(((user) => user.id === id)) ?? null }
        );
    }

    public toggleButtonOnClick$(obs2$, userClick): Observable<void> {
        return userClick.pipe(
            switchMap(() => obs3$),
            switchMap((id) => combineLatest([this.getSomeDataById$(id), of(id)]))
        ).pipe(
            map(([data, id]) => {
                // some code block that gets executed everytime an observable emits new value
            })
        );
```

Once everything finishes, I try to store the users decision after a click is made. So the **userObs$** gets updated, once that happens, the block within toggleButtonOnClick$ is executed again, and not once, but 2 sometimes 3 or 4.

Btw, in the component, the obs2$ im using it on the DOM with Async pipe to show/hide stuff. Maybe that is also triggering the calls after the service observable changes.

I've tried several things already without luck.

Any tip or help or guiding would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As a reader I can't understand what is your goal. I suggest you write down what you are trying to achieve in each step and write it down in plain English.

Comment: @noririco I'll re-write all in a few hours. But the "in plain english" was completely unnecessary.

Comment: @noririco updated, see if it's understandable now.

Comment: And what does the related HTML look like?

Comment: @E.Maggini I'm checking for `this.obs3 | async` in 4 different places. So I assume this is why. For some reason this check is connected to the chain and calling a non-related function. I will update the above to show also the HTML part.

Comment: what happens if you update it to: `this.obs3$ = this.obs2$.pipe(
      switchMap((value) => this.someService.checksAndReturnsBoolean$(value), shareReplay(1))`

Comment: @eko it shows the first click + 2 more executions of the function. I put some console logs there to see it

Comment: @msqar Hi can You explain in short what you are trying to do ? means you work flow and use-case?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Hi, imagine a facebook Like button, where you click on it, changes its state from `unliked` to `liked`, stores this value to backend, and when I retrieve the new user updated posts, it updates the view to show that the post was liked. And of course, you can keep clicking the button to toggle it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aw4fqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here simply I changed state from like to unlike.. and next what you want ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this @GaurangDhorda, and my code works same way, but the problem on mine is that whenever the state is saved and retrieved making one of my observables that im listening to change as well, everything gets triggered when i didn't even click.

Comment: In my case its state$, which Chane independent, when only click on button.

Comment: Can you please support me here https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I found where's the issue! The function within combineLatest is being triggered every time the userObs$ changes. I need to find a way to prevent that.

Comment: I think i solved it by adding take(1) to that specific function. I gotta test more though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was needing was to use shareReplay(1) and take(1) on different functions on my service to make it work as expected without repeating unnecessary calls.

It would end up looking like this:

```
public checksAndReturnsBoolean$(id): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.userObs$.pipe(
           map((users) => { users.some((user) => user.id === id) }),
           take(1)
        );
    }

    public getSomePropBasedOnValue$(id): Observable<SomeObject | null> {
        return this.userObs$.pipe(
           map((users) => { users.find((user) => user.id === id) ?? null }),
           shareReplay(1)
        );
    }
```